# Given matrix A with eigenvalue $\lambda$ and corresponding eigenvector x, prove $A^k$ has eigenvalue $\lambda^k$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given matrix A with eigenvalue $\lambda$ and corresponding eigenvector x, prove $A^k$ has eigenvalue $\lambda^k$ for the same eigenvector x for any positive integer k.

Can I just use the eigenvalue definition Ax = $\lambda$x, divide x on both sides, then raising the power?

Comment: No, you can't divide by a vector. But you can use $$A^kx = A^{k-1}(Ax) = A^{k-1}(\lambda x) = \lambda A^{k-1}x$$ for $k \geqslant 1$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1.)  $Ax = \lambda x$, given.

2.)  Inductive hypothesis: $A^kx = \lambda^k x$ for some positive integer $k$.

3.)  Operate on the equation of (2) with $A$: $A^{k + 1}x = A(A^k x) = A(\lambda^k)x = \lambda^k (Ax) = \lambda^{k + 1} x$.

4.)  Conclude that $A^k x = \lambda^k x$ for all positive integers $k$.

***QED.***

***Note Added in Edit, Tuesday 2 August 2022 8:05 PM PST: ***In these remarks we shall extend and clarify the above, which we observe binds for $\lambda \in \Bbb F$ and $A \in M_{n \times n}(\Bbb F)$, $\Bbb F$ an *arbitrary* field.  We thus have, for $\alpha, \beta \in \Bbb F$, ***1.)*** $\alpha A^kx = \alpha \lambda^kx$, whence ***2.)*** $(\alpha A^k + \beta A^l)x = \alpha A^kx + \beta A^lx = \alpha \lambda^kx + \beta \lambda^lx = (\alpha \lambda^k + \beta \lambda^l)x$, indicating that ***3.)*** $p(A)x = p(\lambda)x$ for any $p(y) \in F[y]$; finally, ***4.)*** if the field $\Bbb F$ is possessed of a norm $\vert \cdot \vert: \Bbb F \to \Bbb R$ under which it is closed in the sense that Cauchy sequences converge to values (points) in $\Bbb F$ (as is the case with $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$), then there is a legitimate context for considering *convergent sequences and series* of powers of $A$.  ***End of Note.***

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: Thanks so much! Didn't consider using induction for matrices.

Comment: Well, technically speaking, the induction is on the integers, but it works here, doesn't it?  Glad to help out, and thanks for the "acceptance"!