# Show that $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalue of $A^2$.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

So my steps are $A^2x=AAx=A\lambda x=\lambda \lambda x=\lambda^2x$, are they correct?

Is it possible to show by  diagonalization, i.e. $PA^2P^{-1}=PAP^{-1}PAP^{-1}=D^2$ in which $\lambda^2$ is for sure a part of $D^2$.

Comment: $A^2x=AAx=A\lambda x=\lambda \lambda x=\lambda^2x$ is correct.

Comment: Diagonalization might not work (there are matrices which are not diagonalizable)

Comment: the second idea also works, with the exception that it might be a Jordan normal form involved.

Comment: You should probably mention that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, but I guess we're supposed to infer it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Given matrix A with eigenvalue $\lambda$ and corresponding eigenvector x, prove $A^k$ has eigenvalue $\lambda^k$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669031/given-matrix-a-with-eigenvalue-lambda-and-corresponding-eigenvector-x-prove)

Answer (score 2):

The first proof is correct. The other one works only if $A$ is diagonalizable.